# Adding Multithreading and error handling - Python Urllib Script pulling URL from CSV

Tags: python, screen-scraping, urllib

I have a really simple script to download a list of URLS from a 2 column CSV. It works but it's very fast.  What is the best way to add multithreading and potentially some error handling as well.

Every few hours It crashes with the following error

```
  File "pcdl2.py", line 17, in <module>
    urllib.urlretrieve(splitted_line[1], splitted_line[0] + "_img" + str(i) + ".jpg")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 98, in urlretrieve
    return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 247, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 215, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 445, in open_https
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1078, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 894, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 856, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1303, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 369, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 599, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 828, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 0] Error
```

**The Script I am using is**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# assuming a csv file with a name in column 0 and the image url in column 1

import urllib

filename = "images"

# open file to read
with open("{0}.csv".format(filename), 'r') as csvfile:
    # iterate on all lines
    i = 0
    for line in csvfile:
        splitted_line = line.split(',')
        # check if we have an image URL
        if splitted_line[1] != '' and splitted_line[1] != "\n":
            urllib.urlretrieve(splitted_line[1], splitted_line[0] + "_img" + str(i) + ".jpg")
            print "Image saved for {0}".format(splitted_line[0])
            i += 1
        else:
            print "No result for {0}".format(splitted_line[0])`
```

Comment: first use `print()` to see values in variables which you use in line which makes problem - and when you get url which makes problem then check if url makes problem in real web browser.

Comment: there are modules which `requests+threading` or `requests+multiprocessing` or `requests+asyncio` and you can use them like normal `requests`. For example: [httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org/)